# GDAL Raster Output

Tags: python, io, arcgis, raster, gdal

I'm trying to create a .tif file using GDAL in python.  It's creating a file, but saying "no preview available" whenever I browse to it.  Right now, I'm just trying to get it to make a copy of the input file.  Here's my code:

```
gdal.AllRegister()

inDs = gdal.Open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\patrick\\Desktop\\tiff elevation\\EBK1KM\\color_a2.tif")
if inDs is None:
  print 'Could not open image file'
  sys.exit(1)
else:
    print "successfully opened input file"

rows = inDs.RasterYSize
cols = inDs.RasterXSize
myband = inDs.GetRasterBand(1)
elev_data = myband.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols,rows)
driver = inDs.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create('C:\\Documents and Settings\\patrick\\Desktop\\tiff elevation\\EBK1KM\\new.tif', cols, rows, 1, GDT_Int32)

if outDs is None:
    print "couldn't open output file"
    sys.exit(1)

outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)
outData = numpy.zeros((rows,cols),numpy.int16)
outBand.WriteArray(elev_data)
outBand.FlushCache()
outBand.SetNoDataValue(-99)
outDs.SetGeoTransform(inDs.GetGeoTransform())
outDs.SetProjection(inDs.GetProjection())
del outData
```

============================update=========================================
made some discoveries...
I've studied ways of converting from one number format to another using statistical normalization.  I processed the input data and transformed it to uint8 by using the following algorithm:

```
std = elev_data.std() #standard dev
avg = elev_data.mean()
arr = numpy.zeros((rows,cols),numpy.uint8)
for _i_ in _range_(_rows_):
    for _j_ in _range_(_cols_):
        arr[i,j] = (((out_elev[i,j]-avg)/std)*127)+128 #normalization formula
        #this puts all vals in range 1 to 255 (uint8)
dr = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outDs = dr.Create("name",cols,rows,3,GDT_Byte) 
#creates and RGB file, accepts uint8 for input
outDs.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr) #write the output as shades of red
#this writes out a format viewable by microsoft products
```

the main reason I wanted to copy was to prove that I could read in, then write out updated data based on calculations.

what might be a way I could write out the output data using a color ramp, instead of shades of just one color?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you're getting "No preview available" from the Windows Picture and Fax Viewer application when trying to preview the TIFF file as an image?  (See below screenshot.)

[image: No preview available screenshot]

Bear in mind that there are [many different flavors of TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format), and not all are the same.  In particular, the Windows Picture and Fax Viewer does not support all kinds of TIFFs.

There is a Microsoft Knowledge Base article [**You Cannot View TIFF Images Using Windows Picture and Fax Viewer**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329270) that says in part:

> Windows Picture and Fax Viewer in Windows XP uses Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI+). GDI+ supports many standard compression algorithms for faxes. However, it may be incompatible with some of the encoding schemes that are not used frequently.

If you're looking for a tool for viewing raster data (including GeoTIFF rasters), I'd recommend the freely available [OpenEV](http://openev.sourceforge.net/), which you can get as part of the [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) package.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I notice:

1. You only copy one band of the source dataset.  If it is a color
   image, it may have 3 bands, or a color map.  If it has a color map,
   you need to copy it over as well.  If it is 3 or 4 bands, you have
   to copy all of the data.
2. `CreateCopy()` is an easier way to do what you are looking for.

Comment: I figured out my issue - I didn't have a proper viewer for the type of output file I was creating.  Int16 is not supported by microsoft products for viewing.  I downloaded and installed Brava Reader, and it's able to view most forms of output I can generate.